# Prevent modification of original array in a loop (foreach) - powershell

Tags: powershell

I need some assistance please, to understand behavior of arrays and powershell loops.
I have stumbled upon a strange array behavior, here is the issue and sample script:

```
# I create simple array
$item2 = New-Object Collections.ArrayList

# getting some sample data for array
$allitems = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" | select name,Attributes

#running loop
foreach ($item in $allitems){

   # outputing iriginal array item
   Write-Host $item

   # addind to new array
   $item2.Add($item)| Out-Null

   # here is the issue I have - after I add member to my $item2 array
   # it is replicated to also $allitems, I don't need this behavior
   # to happen. Also I don't understand why it changes the original
   # $item  and $allitems. Am I creating array copy incorrectly ?

   $item2[-1] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'testproperty' -value 'testvalue'
   write-host "$($item2[-1]) mod"
   Write-Host $item
}
```

result of the script is this :

```
@{Name=rollback2.puc; Attributes=Archive} -> original entry
@{Name=rollback2.puc; Attributes=Archive; testproperty=testvalue} mod -> modified entry
@{Name=rollback2.puc; Attributes=Archive; testproperty=testvalue} -> original entry modified , why ?
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Call `Get-ChildItem -Path` twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most* types of objects in .NET are *reference-type* objects, meaning that what you have stored in `$item` is not the object itself, but a *reference* to it.

When you then call `$item2.Add($item)`, the *reference* is copied to `$item2`, but both the array list and the variable still point back to the exact same object/memory address, and PowerShell will therefore "remember" the added property regardless of which copy of the object reference you use.

In this particular case, you can work around it and create 2 sets of objects by calling `Get-ChildItem` twice:

```
$item2 = New-Object Collections.ArrayList

$allitems = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" | select name,Attributes

foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" | select name,Attributes){
  Write-Host $item

  $item2.Add($item)| Out-Null

  $item2[-1] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'testproperty' -value 'testvalue'

  # the objects stored in $allitems will have been unaffected by the call above
}
```

Or by calling `Get-Item` to create a new object to represent the file just before adding to the array list:

```
$item2 = New-Object Collections.ArrayList

$allitems = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" | select name,Attributes

#running loop
foreach ($item in $allitems){
  Write-Host $item

  # Create a new FileInfo object by calling `Get-Item`
  $itemCopy = $item | Get-Item
  $item2.Add($itemCopy) | Out-Null

  $item2[-1] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name 'testproperty' -value 'testvalue'

  # $item2[-1] has been modified, but $item has not
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !
Your answer helped me understand little more about object references and was able to find that proper cloning of arrays/objects in PowerShell can be done with serialisation also known as deep cloning. 
Running commands twice for different objects works too, only caveat if you have large items or something that takes long time , running twice not always convenient and can have different results for each object ( due to changes in between the runs).